# Maven Not Building Due to Generics

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

So I am on Ubuntu 13.1 and am trying to build my project with maven but it is dying with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/somepath/file.java:[27,11] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
```

I have JAVA_HOME set correctly:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
bin .. other folders ...
```

What gives? Why is it telling me it is trying to compile with the ancient Java 1.3?

Comment: Yes, without your POM we can't help. Chances are you've misconfigured -- or forgotten to configure -- your compiler plugin. It defaults to Java 3, so you have to set it higher to support more modern features.

Comment: Use an more up-to-date [Maven-compiler-plugin version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) cause this one is really old (currently: 3.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at : [Compiler plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)

maven by default builds with java 1.3

For example, under your **build**:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Um it says on that page the default is 1.5

Comment: @thatidiotguy *the plugin* is 1.5 by default, *maven* uses 1.3 by default. To be exact: maven-compiler-plugin in **maven super pom** is configured to 1.3, if you enable this plugin you will get 1.5 by default.

Comment: Ah I see, ok let me try this out quickly - sorry about the confusion. That's how I get my name